# Blazor Material without bootstrap

Tags: c#, progressive-web-apps, matblazor

Is it possible to use Blazor Material without using/referencing the Bootstrap Library ?

I have removed the links to the bootstrap .css files in the Blazor web assembly template and it appears that obviously the bootstrap styles aren't working anymore.
Which is fine as I plan to use a different CSS library such as TailwindCSS.

Is it possible to continue to work with Tailwind and Blazor Material without running into issues that rely on bootstrap if attempting to replace bootstrap with Tailwind and Blazor Material?

Answer (score 3):

Blazor is not connected to Twitter Boostrap (v4) in any way. It is simply the template project to show you various functionality in a pleasant way e.g., menus, `<NavLink />`, alerts, etc.

You can completely remove Bootstrap references and switch to any platform you'd prefer. There will not be any degradation to the Blazor framework. I personally use Bootstrap strictly for the grid system and responsiveness, the rest is custom CSS.

Comment: Notice that css supports grid system without bootstrap as well ;)

Comment: @Fabio Its mainly used for browsers that don't support newer CSS features.